# Написание программы-калькулятора времени проведенного за компьютером

Tags: c#

Пока что только идея, реализация которой ставит в ступор, поэтому своих наработок пока-что нету.

Что должно быть:

1. Подсчет **активного** времени, проведенного в каждом приложении.
2. Подсчет **активного** времени, проведенного на каждой вкладке браузера (реально ли это вообще сделать программно?).
3. Автозагрузка программы вместе с системой.

Программа должна будет запускаться вместе с системой и вести скрытый учет, а работодатель в конце дня, например, сможет посмотреть, чем же занимаются его сотрудники. Т.е., если он (сотрудник) сидел, например, в браузере - необходим учет проведенного времени и на каком сайте, вне зависимости от браузера. Если это месседжер - сколько времени в нем, IDE - сколько в IDE и т.д.

Что интересует сейчас:

1. Реально ли написать это на C#?
2. Какой язык лучше выбрать для написание чего-то подобного?
3. Сколько это займет времени? (Хотя бы ооочень натянутое значение)

Под "активным" временем я понимаю следующее: движение мышкой, нажатие клавиш, клики мышкой, etc.

Comment: Для начала дайте определение "активного" времени

Comment: Программа для default OS? :-)

Comment: @Majestio, скорее всего это будет windows, но, внезапно может оказаться и какой-нибудь дистрибутив Linux, поэтому скорее для uncertain OS :)

Comment: Тут нужно хорошо знать ОС и возможно модифицировать ее под эту задачу. 1) реально (ведь из шарпа можно запускать модули и на др. языках); 2) тот, что лучше знаете (для системозависимых частей, ввероятно, Си); 3) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что интересует сейчас:
>
> Реально ли написать это на C#?

Реально.

> Какой язык лучше выбрать для написание чего-то подобного?

Тот, который лучше знаешь. Буквально недавно попадалась программа-драйвер, написанная на вижуал-васике. А совсем недавно - "Hello world", написанная в шестнадцатеричном редакторе. Я бы не был бы оригинален - выбрал бы С++.

> Сколько это займет времени? (Хотя бы ооочень натянутое значение)

Не спеша - недельку-другую. Но тут основное время, имхо, не само написание (кодирование), а выверка и уточнение ТЗ, и отладка.

> Под "активным" временем я понимаю следующее: движение мышкой, нажатие клавиш, клики мышкой, etc.

А вот это и есть "камень преткновения". Активность нужно определять не одним, а несколькими критериями. Пример: запущен музыкальный плеер (и он имеет фокус), запущена читалка книги, которая попиксельно скролит книжку. Что увидит "работодатель"? Что сотрудник весь день слушал музыку. И таких "критериев" можно набрать много.

Я бы выделил:

- приложение под фокусом ввода
- события от клавы/мыши
- тайм-ауты между событиями
- наличие средств виртуализации на отслеживаемом компе
- наличие удаленных рабочих столов на отслеживаемом компе
- наличие средств эмуляции присутствия, типа AutoIt'а
- название запущенного приложения
- верификация подлинности названия запущенного приложения
- etc...

Вот именно весь этот перебор критериев, имхо, и займет львиную долю разработки. А вешать и снимать хуки - дело гораздо проще.